# How to view attributes of an object in the designated entry boxes on second window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making this football player search app that lets you click on a players name and in the next page/screen it shows the information about that player. What I'm struggling with is when I click the player I want to search and then it brings me to the next screen I want to view the information on the players through their object and attribute. I need help searching the player and it shows the name, team, and their number once they are searched within their designated entry box.

Here is my code, I took away quite a bit to make it a little easier. But I'm just stumped on how to go about solving this.

```
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()
data = ""


class Player:
    """Creating the information for the soccer player"""
    def __init__(self,name,team,number):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.number = number

class Screen:

    def __init__(self,master):
        # Creating the main tkinter window
        self.master = master
        self.search_player()

    def search_player(self):
        """The main search window, this is where you will search for the player"""

        self.string1 = tk.StringVar()
         # Clears first frame
        for i in self.master.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()
        # Create first frame
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=500, height=300)
        self.frame1.pack()
        # Search Label
        self.search_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Search Player:", font=("Times, 12"))
        self.search_label.place(x=15, y=50)


        # Entry for searching
        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, font=("arial, 15"),textvariable=self.string1)
        self.search_entry.place(x=125, y=50)
        # Search Button
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Search", font=("Times, 13"), command=lambda: self.player_info_screen())
        
        self.search_button.place(x=360, y=47)

        # Listbox storing players name
        self.listbox1 = tk.Listbox(self.master,font=("Times, 12"))
        self.listbox1.place(x=125, y=100)

        # Scroll bar for list box
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.scrollbar.place(x=310, y=100)

        # Attaching listbox to scrollbar and scrollbar to listbox
        self.listbox1.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox1.yview())

        # list made up of each object instance showing players name
        footballer_names = [player1.name, player2.name, player3.name]


        # Adding players into listbox
        for name in footballer_names:
            self.listbox1.insert(0, name)

        # Binding for selecting item in listbox
        self.listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.print_selection)



    def print_selection(self, event):
        """Prints out name of selected player from listbox into the search bar"""
        value = self.listbox1.get(self.listbox1.curselection())
        self.string1.set(value)


    def player_info_screen(self):
        """Screen to show picture of player along with info of the player"""
        for i in self.master.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()
        # Create player info frame
        self.frame3 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=500, height=300)
        self.frame3.pack()
        # Place Holder right now
        screen_label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text="Player Info Screen:", font=("Arial, 14"))
        screen_label2.place(x=175,y=10)

        # Show players name when search
        name_label = tk.Label(self.master,text="Name:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        name_label.place(x=15,y=75)
        name_entry = tk.Entry(self.master,font=("Arial, 12"))
        name_entry.place(x=70, y=77)

        # Show Players team when searched
        team_name_label = tk.Label(self.master,text="Team:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        team_name_label.place(x=15,y=115)
        team_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.master,font=("Arial, 12"))
        team_name_entry.place(x=70,y=117)

        # Show players number when searched
        number_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Number:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        number_label.place(x=15,y=155)
        number_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, font=("Arial, 12"))
        number_entry.place(x=80,y=157)


        player_image_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Player Image:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        player_image_label.place(x=340,y=50)


player1 = Player("Neymar","Paris Saint Germain","10")


player2 = Player("Lionel Messi","Inter Miami","30")

player3 = Player("Kevin De Bruyne","Manchester City","17")


window = Screen(root)



root.geometry("500x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a `self.string1` assigned to hold the name of the player once the search button is pressed, all you need to do is get the name from that attribute, then find the corresponding player object, then assign it to the various entry widgets on your second screen.  To do that you could create 3 additional `StringVar`'s in your `search_player` method and assign them to each of the `Entry` boxes. then once done constructing the second window you can pull the info from `self.string1` and fill it in as previously mentioned.

For example:

```
...
...
...

class Screen:

    ...
    ...
    ... 

    def player_info_screen(self):
    
        # Create a string var for each of the entry boxes
        namevar = tk.StringVar()
        teamvar = tk.StringVar()
        numbervar = tk.StringVar()
    
        for i in self.master.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()
        self.frame3 = tk.Frame(self.master, width=500, height=300)
        self.frame3.pack()
        screen_label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text="Player Info Screen:", font=("Arial, 14"))
        screen_label2.place(x=175,y=10)
        name_label = tk.Label(self.master,text="Name:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        name_label.place(x=15,y=75)
        name_entry = tk.Entry(self.master,font=("Arial, 12"), textvariable=namevar)
        name_entry.place(x=70, y=77)

        team_name_label = tk.Label(self.master,text="Team:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        team_name_label.place(x=15,y=115)
        team_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.master,font=("Arial, 12"), textvariable=teamvar)
        team_name_entry.place(x=70,y=117)

        number_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Number:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        number_label.place(x=15,y=155)
        number_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, font=("Arial, 12"), textvariable=numbervar)
        number_entry.place(x=80,y=157)

        player_image_label = tk.Label(self.master, text="Player Image:", font=("Arial, 12"))
        player_image_label.place(x=340,y=50)

        name = self.string1.get()   # get the name currently held in string1
        player = get_player_object(name) # find the corresponding player

        namevar.set(player.name)  # fill in the information
        teamvar.set(player.team)  # in the entry boxes
        numbervar.set(player.number)  # with player details
        
def get_player_object(name):
    """Find player object from player name"""
    for player in [player1, player2, player3]:
        if player.name == name:
            return player
    return Player('','','')   

player1 = Player("Neymar","Paris Saint Germain","10")


player2 = Player("Lionel Messi","Inter Miami","30")

player3 = Player("Kevin De Bruyne","Manchester City","17")


window = Screen(root)



root.geometry("500x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to cater invalid player name input, i.e. when `get_player_object()` return `None`.